# PHP5.6 SSL protocol

Tags: php, openssl

Alguém pode me explicar os possíveis motivos desse erro:

 
**Unable to connect: 35 Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to apisandbox.braspag.com.br:443**

Estou utilizando a biblioteca HttFul(http://phphttpclient.com/docs/class-Httpful.Request.html).

OBS: estou consumindo a api no servidor de homologação.